# Update a field of document using DSL query

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash

I am working on generating logs and then from those logs generating an index. I have generated an index from the logs but now I need to modify a field of all the documents having that field.

Technically there is a field in my document named as status which tells the status of the transaction, In my logstash configuration file I have given a status "Transaction posted on POS" but now I want to change that to "Transaction completed on POS"

It's more like a find and replace query, any idea how can I achieve this using DSL query?

Comment: i don't know about logstash but in Graylog 2 you can simply search for anything including statuses without config changes..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I need a solution for elasticsearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like something you could do with the [update by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/docs-update-by-query.html) API.

You call that API with an Elasticsearch query to pick which documents to update (which can simply be a *match-all* if you want to update all documents) and a Painless script that actually changes the data in those documents.